# Package depended Makevars in install.packages

Tags: r, linux, r-package

Is there a way to force `install.packages` to use diffrent Makevars for diffrent packages?

I can configure the packages args, vars or install options by setting (e.g. in .Rprofile):

```
options(
    configure.args = list(
        ROracle = c("--with-oci-lib=/usr/lib/oracle/xx.yy/client64/lib", "--with-oci-inc=/usr/include/oracle/xx.yy/client64")
        ,udunits2 = "--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2"
    )
    ,configure.vars = list(
        stringi = "ICUDT_DIR=/my/path/to/icu")
    )
    ,INSTALL_opts   = list(
        cairoDevice = "--no-test-load"
    )
)
```

But installation for example the rstan package [require dedicated Makevars](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Linux).

I try to change `R_MAKEVARS_USER` variable to point required Makevars file. Setting it before `R CMD` works:

```
export R_MAKEVARS_USER=/xxx/yy
R CMD install rstan
```

But I use install.packages to install many different packages and I want to use Makevars only for rstan.

My current workaround is to install everything else and then rstan with dedicated Makevars.